# How to set up an HTTP GET fake response

Tags: unit-testing, http, go, mocking

Given a function that makes an HTTP GET in Go:

```
package main

import (
   "net/http"
   "io/ioutil"
)

func CallExample() {
  resp, _ := http.Get("http://example.com/foo")
  body, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
  return body
}
```

How do I set up a test that calls this function (`CallExample`) while avoiding making the actual HTTP GET request?

```
package main

import (
  "testing"
)

func TestCallExample(t *testing.T) {
  // What setup do I need here to fake a response from http://example.com/foo?
  got := CallExample()
  want := "foo"
  if got != want {
    t.Errorf("Got %s, Want %s", got, want)
  }
}
```

I understand there is a `import "net/http/httptest"` library, but it is unclear how to use it to intercept the GET and fake a response. Something to setup with `httptest.NewRecorder()`? It would also be much appreciated if you could show an example where you fake 200/404/500 status codes and different response bodies. Thanks.

**Solution:**

Had to modify `CallExample` to accept a `url` from the `httptest.NewServer()`'s `Server.URL`.

```
func CallExample(url string) (string) {
  resp, _ := http.Get(url)
  body, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
  return string(body)
}

func TestCallExample(t *testing.T) {
  ts := httptest.NewServer(http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "foo")
  })) 
  defer ts.Close()

  got := CallExample(ts.URL)
  want := "foo"
  if got != want {
    t.Errorf("Got %s, Want %s", got, want)
  }
}
```

Comment: @leafbebop this is helpful, but it requires me to modify the signature of CallExample to accept a URL as an argument. The `mockServerURL = ts.URL` confuses me. How would I just make `ts.URL` equal to `http://example.com/foo`?

Comment: @tester, you don't. You have to make the base URL configurable. If you can't change the signature of CallExample, write a new function callExample(string) (which you can test) and change CallExample to simply call it with "http://example.com".